# Django nested URLs

Tags: python, django, django-urls

How do I nest url calls in django? For example, if I have two models defined as

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    body = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    @property
    def comments(self):
        return self.comment_set.all()

class Comment(models.Model):
    comment = models.TextField()
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

With the following url files

root url

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^post/', include('post.urls')),
)
```

post url

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.PostList.as_view()),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.PostDetail.as_view()),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/comments/$', include('comment.urls')),
)
```

comment url

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', CommentList.as_view()),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', CommentDetail.as_view()),
)
```

But when I go to /post/2/comments/1, I am given a Page not found error stating

```
Using the URLconf defined in advanced_rest.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^post/ ^$
^post/ ^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$
^post/ ^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/comments/$
The current URL, post/2/comments/1, didn't match any of these.
```

This is not a problem though when I visit /post/2/comments Is this not allowed by django to have nested URL calls like this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think is probably because you're finishing the regex with the dollar sign `$`. Try this line without the dollar sign:

```
...
url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/comments/', include('comment.urls')),
...
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 6):

You have a `$` at the end of `r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/comments/$'`.

That means Django will only match with that URL when there is nothing after that.

So any longer URLs currently won't be considered. Therefore, you need to update the regular expression to:

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/comments/', include('comment.urls')),
```

Answer (score 0):

Above Django 2.0 you can use simply...

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<pk>/comments/', include('comment.urls')),
]
```